# How many items is it safe to store in a single container?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

While dumping my loot in a non-respawning chest in my home, I noticed some items disappeared from the chest. I assumed they would return once I'd taken some of the items from the chest, but even after removing all the items they were nowhere to be found - neither in the chest nor in my inventory. How many items can I store in a single container before any new items placed there start disappearing?

Comment: Can you say what house you are referring to?

Comment: @Mandemon it was the chest inside the player's private portion of Dunbarrow Cove, from the Thieves Den DLC.

Comment: Hmm, hard to say then. Seems like the game bugged. All containers in home houses are supposed to be save, AKA non-resetting.

Comment: @Mandemon it didn't reset, the item disappeared while I was in the cell, putting more items into that same chest.

Comment: That still sounds like a bug. Container contents have never had a known item limit in the three modern TES games.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I'm certainly not the only one to experience this problem http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1359790 http://forum.teamxbox.com/showthread.php?t=446414

Comment: @kotekzot Those are something different, since you notice the items didn't return after "remove all". There's a known display bug with too many items, but a deliberate limit has never been found, and your experience doesn't sound like the display bug. That's why I comment this sounds like a bug, and not one I've heard of before.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie ah, I see, that is indeed unusual. I'll try and test it a bit more then.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie hmm, I couldn't reproduce this bug with the same chest or a chest in a different player house. Guess I'll leave the question up in case more information becomes available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be a glitch. The [UESP Wiki's "Oblivion: Containers"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Containers) article states that containers do not have a weight or item limit.

From the [UESP wiki's "Oblivion: Minor Glitches - Items Disappearing from Containers"](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Oblivion:Minor_Glitches#Items_Disappearing_from_Containers) article:

> #### Items Disappearing from Containers
>
> Sometimes items appear to disappear from containers if you have
> already put a lot of items in. This is merely a display bug, however:
> if you start removing other items from the container the missing
> item(s) will reappear. Also, if you "Take All", the missing items will
> still be added to your inventory. Saving the game while in the same
> zone as the container then reloading the save will often make all the
> missing items reappear; leaving the room, or looking in other
> containers after reloading, will break the container again.
>
> This glitch seems to be caused by an error in the recorded number of
> items stored in the container. It looks like that number sometimes
> becomes less than the actual number of items stored. This causes the
> most recently added items to not be listed in the container's
> inventory. Often, if you add another item to the container, a previous
> missing one will appear, but instead the new item disappears.
>
> Storing items that you will not be using at equal to or less than 100%
> health will reduce the likelihood of items disappearing. Armor
> repaired to 125% can quickly fill up a container.
>
> Note that if you are using mods which raise your maximum encumbrance,
> the same glitch may also happen to your inventory.

So, if you dump a lot of items inside a container, some of them will appear to vanish, and when you "Take all" some of the items that were hidden in the container will become hidden in your inventory as well.